# Go Front End Interaction with HTML and Go

Tags: html, go

I'm new to Go and I've recently been going through the "Tour of Go" because I think it is/will be a very powerful language to use, much better than PHP and such. It was a big debate between learning Go or Python, but I feel Go is the path of the future.

I'm at the point in my learning that I want to know how to incorporate Go with an actual web page. I have searched everywhere on the web for how to interact with the front end side of things, like HTML, but I cannot find resources anywhere.

I'd like to be able to do your traditional tasks, such as user input from HTML forms, database retrieval, dynamically updating the interface with if say, a username is available or not. Will Go be capable of interacting with the front end of things?

A second question is if Ajax is even needed when using Go.

I know these are really entry-level questions, but I really can't find out how to get Golang to interact with the front end side of things. So if anyone could please provide links to resources you might know of, or example code, that'd be wonderful! Thank you.

Comment: Go is a fully capable, modern language that can do everything you mention in your post: ajax --yes, html forms --yes, and much, much more.  It has many features built into the standard library that you'll want to utilize on your quest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can write a web application with Go. The Go standard library includes most everything you need to build many types of web applications.

The [wiki article](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) on the Go Language website is a good place to learn about how to write a web applicaton with Go.

It's easy to write Ajax applications with Go. As with other server side languages, the use of Ajax is up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great tutorial for interfacing Go with front end interaction!